# Terraform plan -destroy has additional items in red

Tags: terraform

```
terraform plan -destroy
```

gives:

```
- module.instances.aws_instance.ec2InstanceA

- module.instances.data.aws_subnet_ids.subnetIdA


Plan: 0 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
```

I assume it's only going to destroy 1 resource.

But which? I'd like to assume it's the EC2 instance but how do I verify this?

Comment: It must be the instance - the other is `...data...`, so doesn't really exist as a resource in AWS?  Wonder if this is worth logging as a bug - I wouldn't expect to see such things in the output for a `plan -destroy`?

Comment: Looks like [it's already been discussed/changed here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/14048)

Answer (score 0):

One of them - `module.instances.aws_instance.ec2InstanceA` is the resource and the other - `module.instances.data.aws_subnet_ids.subnetIdA` is a data source.

The data source appearing in the destroy plan looks like a bug, similar to one discussed here - https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/14048